# DI: No qualifying bean of type available

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I start to learn Spring.
In my beginner project I want to inject dependency of beans.
https://github.com/anatoliy19/2.1.4.git

```
    To do that, 1) I add in AppConfig method   
    @Bean
    public static Duck5 getDuck(Egg6 egg) {return new Duck5(egg);}

    and 2)
    add a private field in class Duck5: 
     
     @Autowired   
     private Egg6 egg;
    
    
    To my regret, an error has come out:
    [No qualifying bean of type 'koschei.models.Duck5' available][1]: expected single matching bean but found 2: duck5,getDuck
    
    Project is here: https://github.com/anatoliy19/2.1.4.git
```

Answer (score 1):

So from the exception `found 2` I assume you have the bean defined and taking from the `Autowired` field `egg` `Duck5` is annotated with something like `Component`.

So the `Component` annotation already tells spring that it should create a bean for this class and then you create another one in your configuration and thereby Spring doesn't know which bean to take

> Notice the bean names in the exception `getDuck` (your own bean) and `duck5` (just the class name in lower case)

So now you have the options to either just remove the bean you create, remove the annotation and use your bean or use a `Qualifer` to identify the bean so Spring knows which to use.

Comment: thanks. If I want to get class Duck5 as a bean, where should I use this?  @Qualifier("duck5") ?

Comment: When you still have both beans you would place it together with your injection maybe you also need it above the class I'm not really sure :/